# How to load a user's friends list?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

I am trying to create a structure that allows People to log into my app, and create a profile for them. They will also have the ability to look-up, and add friends. They will also have the ability to see there list of current friends, and then see their friends profile.

So, i realized i could utilize googles AppEgnine Data store system for alot of this. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Kinds_and_Identifiers

i had a few questions though. What would be the best way to go about storing users friends list, and managing photo icons of these friends, etc?

The Google Datastore has a option to query with VERY specific options so this would be easy to implement during the search function, or even when a user clicks a friends name to pull up there profile.

I am just wondering what would be the best way to manage the list of friends, and then loading a photo icon for each user? I'm not sure if any of you have seen the facebook app but when you look at your friends list it pulls it up pretty fast and loads the images in the background(probably using an asynctask for this).

Any suggestions or answers?

Thank you!

**EDIT:** My main question is how do i keep track of a users friends list and allow to load the users profile once there name is clicked from the friends list? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Serving images done with app engine app engine hight performance image serving is almost free and very fast. 
Here is an article: http://ikaisays.com/2010/09/08/gwt-blobstore-the-new-high-performance-image-serving-api-and-cute-dogs-on-office-chairs/